# If $A$ is subset of $B$, $B$ is subset of $C$, and $C$ is subset of $A$, then $A = B = C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For all sets $A$, $B$, $C$, if $A$ is subset of $B$, $B$ is subset of $C$, and $C$ is subset of $A$, then $A = B = C$.

This is a true statement and I need to provide a proof? Thus, when a statement is false I need to provide it with counterexample whereas if it is true then it has to be provided by a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes what you say is correct. The statement is an application of the Extensionality Axiom of set theory. Extensionality says that if two sets have the same elements then they are equal. It is easy to see from $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ that an element belongs to $A$ if and only if it belongs to $B$, so by extensionality $A=B$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the claim you state is correct, and you thus need to prove it.

In general whatever you claim you need to supply argument for. Whether you call it a proof or a counterexample depends on the situation. To provide a counterexample is to prove that a claim is wrong by exhibiting that it is wrong for a particular case. To provide a proof is to give a sequence of arguments that establish the statement is correct. If you think logically about what you need to do, then you won't get confused with such irrelevant issues.

For instance, if you want to prove that it is not true that for all real numbers $x$: $x^2> 0$, then you can do it by providing the counterexample $x=0$, since then $x^2=0$, not bigger than $0$. It's a counter example since you showed the claim is incorrect by exhibiting a particular case.

On the other hand, if you want to prove that for all real numbers $x$: $x^2\ge 0$, then you can not do it by observing that for $x=1$ you have $x^2=1>0$, since that still leaves infinitely many other values for you to verify the claim for. Thus, you need to supply a general proof in this case.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove it with set size. Let $\#A$ be the size (order) of $A$,  so if $\#A=n$ holds, then $A$ has $n$ elements. Then $A$ is a subset of $B$, so you get $\#A\leq\#B$. Then you get $$\#A\leq\#B\leq\#C\leq\#A. $$ So you get $\#A\leq\#A$, and it is trivial that only $\#A=\#A$ is possible. So you get $$\#A=\#B=\#C=\#A.$$ And if one set is a subset of the other, and the two sets have the same size, then they have to be the same. Otherwise there is an element in the subset which is not in the original set. But then the subset is not a subset. So $A$, $B$ and $C$ are equal.

Comment: Just a word of warning: This argument only works for finite sets.